# What is the reason for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my code?

Tags: java

I am implementing Graham Scan Algorithm for convex hull in Java.

I am getting this error while running the code. For input string: "10 18"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Graham.SelectMin(Graham.java:110)
    at Graham.GrahamScan(Graham.java:78)
    at Graham.main(Graham.java:41)
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you could provide some code.

Comment: What does "10 18" mean? Does it mean 1 point with coordinates 10 and 18?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: 10 18 is the 1st line from .txt file

Comment: You provided the error message.  What's the code that you wrote that's producing that output?

Answer (score 1):

> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

This means that you're trying to access an element of an empty array. (An array of size 0.)

You need to have a non-negative size of the array to be able to access element at index 0.

For reference, this code for instance, produces the same error:

```
int initialSize = 0;
int[] arr = new int[initialSize];
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Yeah. Check your `SelectMin` method and before accessing the array, check if `arrayName.length > 0` before doing anything. I would also suggest that you change the first letter of the name of every one of your methods to lowercase.

Comment: /**
  * 
  * 
  *
  */
 public class Point {
  public int x;
  public int y;
  public int getX() {
   return x;
  }
  public void setX(int x) {
   this.x = x;
  }
  public int getY() {
   return y;
  }
  public void setY(int y) {
   this.y = y;
  }
  public Point(int x_,int y_){
   x = x_;
   y = y_;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   sb.append(x);
   sb.append(",");
   sb.append(y);
   return sb.toString();
  }
 }

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;

Comment: public class Graham {
 private Point p[];
 private int size;
 private List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Point> list2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
  Graham g = new Graham();
  BufferedReader br ;
  try{
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
   String buf = br.readLine();
   while (buf!=null&&buf!=""){
         StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(buf,",");
      int x = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
      int y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
      list2.add( new Point(x,y)); 
      buf = br.readLine();
   }

Comment: }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
      g.setSize(list2.size());
      Point[] p = new Point[list2.size()];
      Iterator it1 = list2.iterator();
      int i=0;
      while(it1.hasNext()){
       p[i++]= (Point)it1.next();
      }

Comment: g.setP(p);
   g.GrahamScan();
   
  List list = g.getList();
  Iterator it = list.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()){
   Point point = (Point)it.next();
   System.out.println(point);
  }
  
  
 }

   public List<Point> getList() {
  return list;
 }

 public void setList(List<Point> list) {
  this.list = list;
 }

 public Point[] getP() {
  return p;
 }

 public void setP(Point[] p) {
  this.p = p;
 }

 public int getSize() {
  return size;
 }

 public void setSize(int size) {
  this.size = size;
 }

Comment: boolean GrahamScan () {
      SelectMin();  SortPoints();
      if( size > 2){
          int stk[] = new int[size];
       int top = 2;
       stk[0] = 0; stk[1] = 1; stk[2] = 2;
       for (int i = 3; i < size; i++) {
         while (Area(p[stk[top-1]], p[stk[top]], p[i]) < 0)
      top--;
         stk[++top] = i;
       }      
       for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
         list.add(p[stk[i]]); 
      }else{
       for (int i=0;i< size;i++){
        list.add(p[i]);
       }
      }      
      return true;
    }

Comment: static int Area (Point p0, Point p1, Point p2) {
      int dx1 = p1.x - p0.x, dy1 = p1.y - p0.y;
      int dx2 = p2.x - p0.x, dy2 = p2.y - p0.y;
      return dx1 * dy2 - dx2 * dy1;
    }

       void SelectMin () {
      int ym = p[0].y;
      int m = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (ym > p[i].y || (ym == p[i].y && p[m].x > p[i].x)) {
        ym = p[i].y; m = i;
        }
      }
      SwapPoints(0, m);
    }

Comment: // It Sorts the points
   void SortPoints () {
      for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
   if (Area(p[0], p[i], p[j]) < 0)
     SwapPoints(i, j);
    }
   void SwapPoints (int i, int j) {
      Point tmp;
      tmp = p[i]; p[i] = p[j]; p[j] = tmp;
    }

}

Comment: I added Graham.java in # of comments 1 by 1.

Comment: 2 2 and 3 3 o/p is 1 1 and 3  3

Answer (score 0):

it means that on line `110 of Graham.java` you are trying to access an array index that is either `< 0` or that is `> the length of your array`, can't tell exactly which array without code.

Also `Graham.SelectMin(Graham.java:110)` shows that you are naming method calls in a non-idiomatic Java way. In Java method calls should be in `lowerCamelCase`, such as `Graham.selectMin();`

In Java `UpperCamelCase` is reserved for `ClassNames`.

Comment: This is my code :    /**
  * 
  *
  *
  */
 public class Point {
  public int x;
  public int y;
  public int getX() {
   return x;
  }
  public void setX(int x) {
   this.x = x;
  }
  public int getY() {
   return y;
  }
  public void setY(int y) {
   this.y = y;
  }
  public Point(int x_,int y_){
   x = x_;
   y = y_;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   sb.append(x);
   sb.append(",");
   sb.append(y);
   return sb.toString();
  }
 }

Also==========================

Comment: file name: case1.txt1 1
2 2
3 3